# Using purrr to apply cumulative function

Tags: r, purrr

For each position of x, I want to count how many numbers were > 5. 
Here is my code, using for loop:

```
x<-c(2,8,4,9,10,6,7,3,1,5)

y <- vector()
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  x1 <- x[1:i]
  y <- c(y, length(x1[x1>5]))
}
> y
 [1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Can you help me do it using purrr. Can purrr::reduce be used here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `accumulate()` from `purrr`:

```
accumulate(x > 5, `+`)
#[1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

---

It's basically a wrapper around `Reduce()` with `accumulate = TRUE`

```
accumulate <- function(.x, .f, ..., .init) {
  .f <- as_function(.f, ...)

  f <- function(x, y) {
    .f(x, y, ...)
  }

  Reduce(f, .x, init = .init, accumulate = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`cumsum` function can do this

```
cumsum(x>5)
#[1] 0 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: @Brani asked for a solution that makes use of purrr functions.

Comment: @amarchin I added an approach using `base R` because I believe that no one add a package when it can be done using base function unless it gives a huge benefit.